# I want to add a widget like shubify in shopify online store in add section

Tags: widget, shopify, shopify-app

I am creating a shopify app for merchants. I have created the app, but Now I want to create the widget that can be embaded in the add section of merhants stores like shubify.
[image]

I read the whole documentation of dev.shopify but i didn’t able to find how to add the widget in th e stores

Comment: Check this for the same, its called [Theme APP extensions](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/theme-app-extensions)